# Installing canon LBP5000 laserjet printer

Tags: 11.04, printing, canon

I have the following 
**setup**:

- Ubuntu Natty (11.04) server edition installed
- Printer Canon LBP5000 laserjet
- CUPS, using the web interface because I have no gui. Im operating the system by ssh via my network

**My problem**:
It just doesn't want to print, Im trying to print a test page but nothing is happing. After a while it gives me a error like

> Can't connect to CCPD: Connection refused

Or

> ccp send_data error, exit

**My attempts**:

- I have followed this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190 . The command "ccpd status" gives me the correct output :

  > Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS: ccpd: 4171 4170
- I have tried this script: http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/, same results

Can someone help me with this, cause Im really out of options.

Answer (score 1):

I am using:

- Ubuntu version 11.04
- A Canon LBP500 connected via the network

When I followed Guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190 I got my printer working, but captstatusui (showing printer status in a GUI) gave a bufferoverflow.

When using script: http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu printing and captstatusui worked perfectly, but after a while my Update Manager complained I had a partial finished install and removed the drivers again. Maybe something to do with not specifying a correct package repository?

Anyhow, I made a copy of the working captstatusui binary, let the update manager remove the drivers installed via the script of Radu Cotestcu. Now I have the drivers installed according the first Guide, and use them in combination with the copied version of captstatusui.

Maybe not that elegant, but it works for me

Comment: Thnx for your reply, but I have some questions left. Did you install the printer for the first time? Is the printer directly attached to the netwerk or by another computer? and most important: how do I clean up the mess of my previous installation attemps.

Answer (score 1):

If Status monitor reports error "Check the DevicePath of /etc/ccpd.conf", then you probably don't have usblp kernel module. Run the following command:

```
lsmod | grep usblp
```

If it outputs nothing, load the module and restart ccpd:

```
sudo modprobe usblp
ls -l /dev/usb/lp0
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd restart
```

Note: As of Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot), usblp has been deprecated and will not be automatically loaded when you connect your USB printer (see bug #842823]).

If the status monitor works but printing does not, make sure that /var/ccpd/fifo0 actually exists:

```
ls -l /var/ccpd
```

When missing, it can be added manually:

```
sudo mkdir /var/ccpd
sudo mkfifo /var/ccpd/fifo0
sudo chown -R lp:lp /var/ccpd
```