# Canon LBP 3050 laser printer problem

Tags: printing, canon

Ubuntu failed to recognize or find drivers automatically for Canon LBP 3050 Laser printer (USB connected). So I downloaded Linux device driver from the Canon website and installed. And Ubuntu accepted it. But when I try to print something... Nothing happens (means do not print it). What should I do to correct this error?

Comment: Have you tried the guide here? (help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190). i see LBP3050 is listed but not verified. have installed mine with that guide and with the manual. see this: http://askubuntu.com/a/106260/47206

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not work as this Canon driver uses some kernel modules which are blacklisted (i.e. prevented from loading) by default.

I suggest you uninstall the current Canon driver and follow the instructions here: [CanonCaptDrv190](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190) (make sure to read the README file before proceeding).

Comment: Hard to find a permanent solution for this issue of Canon LBP printers but the best solution I was able to find was to restart again and again the procedures at the given address. Pay attention at the bugs discussed in the end and the (very relative) solution.

Answer (score 0):

yes elqaton,
and may be [Canon printer](http://go4download.com/download-canon-lbp-3050-drivers) driver files has be corrupted to and others issues will be reason for usb not detecting the printer, uninstall and re installation will solve these type of problems