# My printer requires "modprobe" and "ccpd" to be started after every system restart.

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon, modprobe

In each time I start my Ubuntu 12.04 computer I need to type the following commands to get my Canon LBP 2900 printer working. Otherwise the status monitor says "Communication Error". I am using driver version 2.40.

```
sudo modprobe usblp 
ls -l /dev/usb/lp0 
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start
```

Comment: Did you try Starting/stopping on USB add/Remove on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190

Comment: I tried it. No progressive result

Comment: Have you tried running the script containing above lines at boot time?

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: how can run that script at boot time in ubuntu 12.04

Comment: i guess initially you were in 11.10? better for 12.04 and 12.10 try uninstalling/reinstalling drivers and use the step-by-step guide here (http://askubuntu.com/a/106260/47206) tested in 12.10 for a printer from the same list (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190#Supported_Printers_Canon_CAPT_Driver_v2.4)

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/modules` and append `usblp`. This will load the `usblp` module at boot time.

To get `/etc/init.d/ccpd` to start, you will need to have links to the `/etc/rc?.d` directories. Read `man update-rc.d` and `man insserv` and look for an LSB (Linux Standard Base, see [Wikipedia for LSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base)) header in `/etc/init.d/ccpd` (begins with `### BEGIN INIT INFO`). I know nothing about `ccpd`.