# Unable to use canon LBP printer after upgrading ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

I had used canon LBP2900B (laserjet) in Ubuntu 10.04 earlier after installing steps as suggested by [Radu Kotescu's site](http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/).

After upgrading to 12.04.1 I see that printer options are available as usual but not a single page can be printed. If I open a PDF document by evince and try to print a page, the following message appears on the terminal: `

```
**WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-9mrPtj/pkcs11: No such file or directory**.
```

Another change I notice is that earlier it was normal to see two printers in the options for printers after installation was completed and installation details suggested which one is to be made the default printer for my purpose. These are available now also but the default printer option had automatically changed (to the best of my knowledge).

Please suggest some way to make the printer work. I understand the previous driver downloaded from Radu Kotescu's site was specifically for 10.04 and now I am running 12.04. So the situation a bit complicated. (Please also note that apparmor is in enforced mode, relevant profile being `/usr/sbin/cupsd`, but this was same in 10.04 version) What should I do now?

Comment: uninstall and reinstall drivers - see http://askubuntu.com/a/106260/47206 and the ubuntu documentation site linked there

Answer (score 0):

You might find some help here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters/CanonPrinters.