# Canon LBP 2900 printer for Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, printing, canon

I had to recreate my computer and have installed Ubuntu 13.04 as my main OS. As a printer I would like to install a Canon iSensys LBP 2900 printer.
The printer-setup recognizes the device, but it won'T allow me to install the proper driver for this device - simply because there seems to be none available. Is that true?

I checked the various similar topics about this issue, but they are either outdated and the data-packages (drivers) are not available anymore or about older/ earlier Ubuntu versions.

Thank you for any advice or help or support.

Best wishes!
Liam

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 13.10, do this first:

Install the portreserve package:

```
sudo apt-get install portreserve
```

[How to make LBP-1120 Canon printer work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105891/how-to-make-lbp-1120-canon-printer-work)