# LBP1120 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, printing, 14.04, canon

I have cannon **LBP1120** with **Ubuntu 14.04** (amd64). For previous versions of Ubuntu the guide:

[How to make LBP-1120 Canon printer work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105891/how-to-make-lbp-1120-canon-printer-work/106260#106260)

worked flawlessly, but for this version the **capstsui** shows me:

```
Check the DevicePath of /etc/ccpd.conf
```

and accordingly printing does not work.

The `ccpadmin` gives me:

```
 CUPS_ConfigPath = /etc/cups/
 LOG Path        = None
 UI Port         = 59787

 Entry Num  : Spooler   : Backend   : FIFO path     : Device Path   : Status 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [0]    : LBP1120   : ccp       : //localhost:59787     : /dev/usb/lp0     :
```

Also I get the two numbers:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status
/usr/sbin/ccpd: 9507 9506
```

And printer is connected:

```
ls -l  /dev/usb/lp0 
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 0 May  2 09:36 /dev/usb/lp0
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After numerous attempts I found a way to get my LBP1120 to work by using *32 bit* driver instead of *64 bit* one. Following:
[Can't get my Canon LBP printer to run under Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04/464334#464334) my solution to the problem is as follows:

### Installing the Linux capt driver

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libxml2:i386 zlib1g:i386 libpopt0:i386
apt-get install cups

wget # I will fix soon but Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN.tar.gz

# Now the system is prepeared for 32 bit driver
dpkg -i Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN/32-bit_Driver/Debian/*.deb
```

### Configuring LBP1120

```
lpadmin -p LBP1120 -m CNCUPSLBP1120CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59687
lpadmin -p LBP1120 -E
ccpdadmin -p LBP1120 -o /dev/usb/lp0

# Not sure if works flawlwslly but this should start ccpd driver on boot
update-rc.d ccpd defaults
```

Now you should connect the printer and try to get two numbers of command:

```
/etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

by starting (from my experience I do this until it works) and stopping:

```
 /etc/init.d/ccpd stop
 /etc/init.d/ccpd start
```

Now if you have managed to get the two magical numbers then you are ready to open *captstatusui* with:

```
captstatusui -P LBP1120
```

and see if your printer shows that it is ready to print. If you at this point get the message:

```
Check the followings:
-Is the printer turned on?
-Is the cable correctly connected?
```

then try to detach other USB peripherals (for example Logitech K360 had interfered)